# Rewrite + JBoss Modules

Tags: url-rewriting, wildfly-8

[Rewrite](http://www.ocpsoft.org/rewrite) doesn't work for **multiple** WARs on Wildfly 8.2.  I used JBoss Modules (jboss-deployment-structure.xml) to import Rewrite classes (my WEB-INF/lib is empty).

I had to bootstrap it by configuring the web.xml, as described here: 
http://www.ocpsoft.org/rewrite/docs/configuration/install

even though I'm using Servlet 3.1, and not using an EAR because the annotation @RewriteConfiguration and provider registration file in META-INF/services are being ignored.

This is my jboss-deployment-structure.xml:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment>
    <dependencies>
      <module name="org.ocpsoft.rewrite" meta-inf="export"/>
    </dependencies>
  </deployment>  
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Note that Rewrite works for multiple WARs if the jars are in WEB-INF/lib. But I'm wondering what's the logic inside Rewrite or JBoss Modules causing this issue. AFAIK, there are separate class loaders for each WAR: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly

This is the exception:

15:25:08,154 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-2) UT005023: Exception handling request to /sakila/ActorManagement: java.lang.RuntimeException: **Error instantiating class** com.test.RewriteConfigurationProvider
        at org.ocpsoft.common.services.ServiceLoader.loadEnriched(ServiceLoader.java:342) [rewrite-servlet-2.0.9.Final.jar:2.0.9.Final]
        at org.ocpsoft.common.services.ServiceLoader.loadClass(ServiceLoader.java:243) [rewrite-servlet-2.0.9.Final.jar:2.0.9.Final]
        at org.ocpsoft.common.services.ServiceLoader.reload(ServiceLoader.java:158) [rewrite-servlet-2.0.9.Final.jar:2.0.9.Final]
        at org.ocpsoft.common.services.ServiceLoader.iterator(ServiceLoader.java:394) [rewrite-servlet-2.0.9.Final.jar:2.0.9.Final]
        at org.ocpsoft.common.util.Iterators.asList(Iterators.java:40) [rewrite-servlet-2.0.9.Final.jar:2.0.9.Final]
        at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.init(RewriteFilter.java:131) [rewrite-servlet-2.0.9.Final.jar:2.0.9.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:111) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:85)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:97) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.createFilter(ManagedFilter.java:79) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.getFilter(ManagedFilter.java:65) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.DisableCacheHandler.handleRequest(DisableCacheHandler.java:33) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
**Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalArgumentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type ApplicationSettings with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject** com.test.RewriteConfigurationProvider.applicationSettings
  at com.test.RewriteConfigurationProvider.applicationSettings(RewriteConfigurationProvider.java:0)
        at org.jboss.weld.manager.InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.createInjectionTarget(InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.java:82) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
        at org.jboss.weld.manager.InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.createInjectionTarget(InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.java:70) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
        at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.createInjectionTarget(BeanManagerImpl.java:1118) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
        at org.jboss.weld.util.ForwardingBeanManager.createInjectionTarget(ForwardingBeanManager.java:201) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
        at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.cdi.CdiServiceEnricher.enrich(CdiServiceEnricher.java:74) [rewrite-integration-cdi-2.0.9.Final.jar:2.0.9.Final]
        at org.ocpsoft.common.services.ServiceLoader.loadEnriched(ServiceLoader.java:324) [rewrite-servlet-2.0.9.Final.jar:2.0.9.Final]
        ... 41 more